# How to overwrite implementation of the function or intercept call to it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I angularjs when modal window from bootstrap is opened it provides two functions, $dismis and $close, on modal window $scope. I need an event to be fired just before either one of these is called. Currently code in controller looks like this

```
  $scope.$emit("ModalClosing");
  $scope.$close(payload);
```

What I would like is to eliminate need to call $emit manually, I want to be able to do

$scope.$close(payload), so that the implementation of $close function does steps above. How would one achieve that? It probably needs something like what mocking framework use. I basically need to intercept call to the function and call my code, and then call original function.

Update: After I posted the question I thought why not just replace it with my implementation. I cannot believe that it is so simple. Is this right? Is there a better way?

```
        var closeModal = $scope.$close;
        $scope.$close = function (payload) {
            $scope.$emit("ModalClosing");
            closeModal(payload);
        };
```

Comment: are you doing this in jasmine?

Comment: change the source in the library to fit your needs? It's open-source for a reason...

Comment: @Mosho That can become problematic if/when you update the library/framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted the question I thought why not just replace it with my implementation. I cannot believe that it is so simple. Is this right? Is there a better way?

```
 var closeModal = $scope.$close;
 $scope.$close = function (payload) {
      $scope.$emit("ModalClosing");
      closeModal(payload);
 };
```